# Latency issues on local development server

Tags: control-panel

I do craft development on a local setup (using a virtual .dev host). The one very annoying issue I experienced is a large latency (~10s) I get while using the backend – f.e. saving an fresh entry or creating a new field. The latency vanishes as soon as I disconnect from the internet. Is there any "call home" function build into craft that causes the delay?

Comment: Welcome to the neighborhood, m9dfukc! It might help to add a bit of detail about your local setup, since there a lot of factors in play here and the problem may not expressly relate to calls home.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I resolved my problem - which was unfortunately *not related to craft* at all. For unknown reasons there it was just quite evident visible.

**Facts:**
I'm running MAMP on a local OSX (Yosemite) setup. My craft website is running on a virtual domain pointing to localhost. 
PHP 5.4
Mysql 5.x
Craft 2.3.26 Pro version

**Issue:**
Long latency (~10s) when editing an entry/adding stuff.

**Solution:**
In the end it was related to OSX issues with resolving a vhost address and resulting in loopbacks. A detailed description of the issue und how to resolve it can be found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064581/how-can-i-eliminate-slow-resolving-loading-of-localhost-virtualhost-a-2-3-secon).

Answer (score 1):

Craft does use cURL to connect to web services at buildwithcraft.com and there is a 30 second timeout if there is no response from our end.

It will then cache that there was a connection error and not attempt to call home again for the next 5 minutes.

If there is a cURL configuration problem, then check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder for any `[error]` or `[warning]` entries and it will tell you what the error message is.